# smbclient command often fails

Tags: c, linux, smb

I need to download files from an old Samba server and delete them afterward.
In order to delete theses files, for each downloaded files, I use the command:

```
smbclient ... -c "cd <destination folder>; rm <filename>"
```

with the `system()` function.

Overall, this works but quite often the Samba server fails to execute the command, until now I saw 3 kind of error messages:

- NT_STATUS_PIPE_BROKEN (the most frequent one)
- NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_INVALID
- NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET

There is also cases with no error message but the file wasn't deleted and even 2 times when it responded `"NT_STATUS_OK removing remote directory file ..."` but the directory is still there afterward while it usually don't send this message.

Is there a way to detect when it fails and redo the command? Or a more reliable way to delete those files?

EDIT : `smbclient ... -c "cd <destination folder>; recurse; prompt; rm <filename>"`

this way, I stop the NT_STATUS_... errors`but the files aren't deleted.

EDIT 2 : I tried to execute the command with exec function and checked the exit value with WEXITSTATUS, I get 1 every time;

Comment: if you want to get informations about an executed command you may use `exec` family functions instead of the `system()` function

Comment: @daouzli I checked with execlp and WEXITSTATUS always return 1